# Facebook Pixels: Separate standard events by pixel ID

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics

I have to implement two (new) Facebook pixels: one site-wide, and one only on specific pages. The requester asked that each pixel only track its own associated standard events.

**Pixel 1:**

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '111');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
</script>
```

**Pixel 2:**

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '222');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
```

Pixel 1 shouldn't receive any Lead tracking data, and Pixel 2 shouldn't receive any ViewContent tracking data. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have almost the same problem. If I add a custom Event like Lead or ViewContent to both of the pixels I get an error in the Facebook Pixel helper that one is called multiple times.

Comment: I see no way for this to be possible as the fbq object share a global namespace on the window object. As far as I can tell, the Facebook pixel is designed to work with a single instance. I have posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902063/is-it-possible-to-push-tracking-events-to-two-separate-facebook-pixels

Answer (score 0):

i struggled myself with this same issue and it seems that Facebook does not publicly support or documents this kind of functionality. Even though it might be essential in many scenarios.

As the post Jason FB shows you can rewrite de fbq function to take the pixel ID as a parameter. Yet, I wanted to accomplish this without having to rewrite the provided fbq:

here is the (***unorthodox***) code of how I came by solving this:

```
function customFacebookTrack(id, eventName, object){


    // If i get an ID i Simply delete the remanent IDs from de FBQ object.
    if(typeof id != 'undefined' && id != 'ALL'){

        var placePixels = [];
        var currentPixels = fbq.getState().pixels;

        //console.log(currentPixels);
        for(i = 0; i < currentPixels.length; i++){
            if(currentPixels[i].id != id){
                placePixels.push(currentPixels[i]);
                currentPixels.splice(i, i + 1);
            }
        }       
    }   

    //console.log(currentPixels);
    // I send my event only with the pixel(s) I want
    fbq('trackCustom', eventName, object);

    // After sending the event I set back the deleted IDs for regular use. 
    if(typeof id != 'undefined' && id != 'ALL'){
        for(i = 0; i < placePixels.length; i++){
            if(placePixels[i].id != id){
                currentPixels.push(placePixels[i]);
                placePixels.splice(i, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this is not a recommended practice by any means. This is a just a workaround to a known limitation of the Facebook event tracking javascript.

Example Snippet:

```
<script>
    customFacebookTrack(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, 'Lead Form', {content_name:'Newsletter Subscriber'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the both tracking event with all init pixel ID

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '111');
fbq('init', '222');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
```