# Is it possible to push tracking events to two separate Facebook Pixels?

Tags: facebook

see Facebook Pixel docs (new as of 2016): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/using-the-pixel

Is it possible to push the same events to two different Facebook pixels at the same time? As far as I can tell, there is one instance of `fbq` created by the pixel code, it accepts one init call (specifying a single FB Pixel init) and all subsequent events are tied to the correct initialization of the single object.

Comment: I don't think it is possible within a single HTML document. You could perhaps use iframes to load different HTML documents that each embed the pixel script with a different id, and then instruct them from the "outside" which events to track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "init" event multiple times with different pixel IDs, all of the initialized pixels will receive all future events.

Comment: Hey Bryan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, that link that you shared appears to be inaccessible without a Facebook at Work account. Please make sure to include all relevant details directly in your answer instead of linking to outside resources. Happy answering!

Comment: I have removed the non-public link

Comment: This DOES appear to work. Note that you will also want to loop over the NOSCRIPT image tag (in addition to the advice in this answer), and repeat it several times too. Accepting as answered.

Answer (score 3):

### Multiple Facebook Pixels Code

In order to be able to trigger distinct events to different Facebook pixels, without having it called to all previously initialized Facebook pixels, you can overwrite the *fbq* function (by copying and pasting the snippet below to your code base) and then call the tracking events as explained on the **Usage** section below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var fbq = (function() {
    function fbq()
    {
      if(arguments.length > 0) {
        var action, pixel_id, type_track, content_obj;

        if( typeof arguments[0] == "string") action = arguments[0];
        if( typeof arguments[1] == "string") pixel_id = arguments[1];
        if( typeof arguments[2] == "string") type_track = arguments[2];
        if( typeof arguments[3] == "object") content_obj = arguments[3];

        var params = [];
        if(typeof action == "string" && action.replace(/\s+/gi, "") != "" &&
        typeof pixel_id == "string" && pixel_id.replace(/\s+/gi, "") != "" &&
        typeof type_track == "string" && type_track.replace(/\s+/gi, "")) {

          params.push("id=" + encodeURIComponent(pixel_id));
          switch(type_track) {
            case "PageView":
            case "ViewContent":
            case "Search":
            case "AddToCart":
            case "InitiateCheckout":
            case "AddPaymentInfo":
            case "Lead":
            case "CompleteRegistration":
            case "Purchase":
            case "AddToWishlist":
            params.push("ev=" + encodeURIComponent(type_track));
            break;
            default:
            return;
          }

          params.push("dl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href));
          params.push("rl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer));
          params.push("if=false");
          params.push("ts=" + new Date().getTime());

          if(typeof content_obj == "object") {
            for(var u in content_obj) {
              if(typeof content_obj[u] == "object" && content_obj[u] instanceof Array) {
                if(content_obj[u].length > 0) {
                  for(var y=0; y<content_obj[u].length; y++) { content_obj[u][y] = (content_obj[u][y]+"").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gi, "").replace(/\s+/gi," ").replace(/,/gi, "§"); }
                  params.push("cd[" + u + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(content_obj[u].join(",").replace(/^/gi, "[\"").replace(/$/gi, "\"]").replace(/,/gi, "\",\"").replace(/§/gi, "\,")));
                }
              }
              else if(typeof content_obj[u] == "string")
              params.push("cd[" + u + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(content_obj[u]));
            }
          }

          params.push("v=" + encodeURIComponent("2.5.0"));

          if(typeof window.jQuery == "function") {
            var iframe_id = new Date().getTime();
            jQuery("body").append("<img height='1' width='1' style='display:none;width:1px;height:1px;' id='fb_" + iframe_id + "' src='https://www.facebook.com/tr/?" + params.join("&") + "' />");
            setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#fb_" + iframe_id).remove(); }, 1000);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return fbq;
  });

  window.fbq = new fbq();
})();
</script>
```

### Usage

Now the *fbq* function takes 3 parameters. The first param will be just "track". The second one is new, that's where you can specify the Facebook pixel ID you want to use to track this specific event. Third, as usual, say the event name. And, lastly, you can pass other options such as purchase value, currency, content_ids, etc.

```
<script>
  fbq('track', '<FIRST_PIXEL_ID>', 'PageView');
  fbq('track', '<FIRST_PIXEL_ID>', 'Purchase', {value: 79.9, currency: 'BRL'});
  fbq('track', '<SECOND_PIXEL_ID>', 'Purchase', {value: 89.9, currency: 'BRL'});
</script>
```

> Note that you can also use different purchase values for different
>   pixels, and they will only be fired to that very specific pixel.

### Demo

You can find the results [in this product page](https://www.touts.com.br/artes/chakra-do-coracao-anahata), though I didn't use different data on the product page. But I use it to trigger Purchase events with different purchase values on the checkout. Also, if you don't have it yet, please download the [Facebook Pixel Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?hl=en) extension for Google Chrome. It'll help you debugging the Facebook Pixel.

Comment: thank you for the demo and "Usage" example. I believe the other example (in section marked "Multiple Facebook Pixels Code") is from a part of your codebase that is not relevant to this question. In fact, @bryan karas's answer (already accepted) is more succinct (although yours provide a good code example here on "Usage")

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but I have left his as the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: Hi Jason, the code in "Multiple Facebook Pixels Code" is actually what makes it possible to trigger events with distinct data to different pixels on the same page. On Bryan's answer, he states that events would be triggered to all initialized pixels. That code for was the actual solution. I'll update my answer to make it clearer. Thanks anyways for the feedback!

Comment: What I don't understand about your answer is that ```fbq``` is defined by the Facebook Javascript. So basically your answer is to overwrite Facebook's own Javascript, which sounds dangerous. (Having said that, using an undocumented part of the API — the ability to push more than 1 pixel— is also dangerous.) But if it is built-in to the FB Javascript, why re-write their Javascript at all?

Comment: I understand your concern, but that's the only way I found to track different events to different pixels on the same page. Please let me know if you find any other workaround :)

Comment: OH I see. Yes I understand why you need the special code. In my use case we wanted to fire the same set of events to two different pixels which makes our use cases different. I will make a small modification to the question. I'd suggest you ask & answer you own SO question, distinct from this one, about pushing different events to different pixels.

Comment: Changed "possible to push events" to "possible to push the same events" in original question.

Comment: Oh! Okay, so you really don't need all that. I've shared my answer here because I couldn't find anything on StackOverflow and your question was the one to always pop up on my searches.

Comment: Absolutely BRILLIANT! Thank you for sharing this snippet!

Comment: @FlavioWuensche I loaded this up and getting an error with `Conversion Pixel` and see the same on your site. Seems everything else is good. Have you noticed this error? BTW...saved me a ton of time with this script..thank you!

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the error for the Conversion Pixel, but it also says "The conversion pixel code on this page didn't load, so no information was sent to Facebook". I don't mind this error as soon as it's working, but if you're able to fix it please let me know. Besides that, it works nicely.

Comment: @FlavioWuensche You can use  fbq('trackSingle',